# JNI GetShortArrayElements fails with SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, kotlin

I've created a buffer in managed code:

```
var nativeBuffer = ShortArray(bufferSize)
```

This is Kotlin code, but according to the [stdlib documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-short-array/), this syntax is effectively a wrapper that returns a `short []`.

I would then like to write to this buffer from C++, using JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_package_class_name_readNext
    (JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jshortArray javaArray)
{
    jboolean * isCopy;
    short * targetArray = env->GetShortArrayElements(javaArray, isCopy);

    // Do stuff to targetArray
}
```

The problem is that the `GetShortArrayElements` call always results in a crash, with the following tombstone:

```
11-07 21:23:53.610 86-86/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-07 21:23:53.610 86-86/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:5.1/LMY47D/buildbot06092001:userdebug/test-keys'
11-07 21:23:53.610 86-86/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
11-07 21:23:53.610 86-86/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
11-07 21:23:53.610 86-86/? I/DEBUG: pid: 28339, tid: 28477, name: Thread-282  >>> <package-name> <<<
11-07 21:23:53.610 86-86/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xb3bcfacb
11-07 21:23:53.613 86-86/? I/DEBUG:     eax b3bcfacb  ebx b3ffcaa4  ecx a2497000  edx b426e480
11-07 21:23:53.613 86-86/? I/DEBUG:     esi a2497000  edi b3fff440
11-07 21:23:53.613 86-86/? I/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 000000e7  xss 0000007b
11-07 21:23:53.613 86-86/? I/DEBUG:     eip b3dcd69c  ebp 9f5a2968  esp 9f5a2880  flags 00210282
11-07 21:23:53.613 86-86/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 002e069c  /system/lib/libart.so (short* art::JNI::GetPrimitiveArray<_jshortArray*, short, art::mirror::PrimitiveArray<short> >(_JNIEnv*, _jshortArray*, unsigned char*)+572)
11-07 21:23:53.613 86-86/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0010cdad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetShortArrayElements(_JNIEnv*, _jshortArray*, unsigned char*)+125)
```

`javaArray` is not null (usually an address like -1621480864) and `nativeBuffer` is a static variable, so not likely to be GC'ed. The behavior occurs on Genymotion instances (x86) and on ARM devices, but I've only tested against Android 5.0+. What else could I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, you're not using the `isCopy` argument correctly. It should be:

```
jboolean isCopy;
jshort* targetArray = env->GetShortArrayElements(javaArray, &isCopy);
```

That is, `isCopy` is an "out parameter" (to use C# lingo).

If you don't care whether the `targetArray` is aliased to `javaArray`, you can also pass `nullptr` instead, like so:

```
jshort* targetArray = env->GetShortArrayElements(javaArray, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Target array should be **jshort** rather than **short**.

Also you need to pass **isCopy** by reference using **&** instead of by value.

More info here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17382